# Is there a way to find out if the "ion-item-sliding" is back in idle position after dragging?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I want to integrate the ion-item-sliding element in my app.

The Item is transparent so the problem is that I can see the left and the right ion-item-option at the same time. That does not look good.

When I slide to the right -> the "ion-item-option" on the right side should not be visible. Same goes the other way around.

To get the drag position I use the (ionDrag) method on the ion-item-sliding.
In the documentation it says that the (ionDrag) emits when the sliding position changes, but it is only fired when I actively drag the item.

As soon as I release the item and it goes back into the idle position, which should be 0, the (ionDrag) stops emitting the position.
So that I am nerver able to determine if the position is 0 after dragging.
Is there a way to handle this problem?

Here is my HTML:

```
<ion-item-sliding id="item_{{i}}" (ionDrag)="onDrag($event)">
   <ion-item-options side="start">
       <ion-item-option expandable>Gekauft</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>

    <ion-item button (click)="openAmountItem(i)">
       <ion-avatar slot="start">
          <ion-img src="{{product.img}}"></ion-img>
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
           <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
           <p class="amount-label">
             {{product.amount}}
           </p>
         </ion-label>
         <ion-label slot="end" color="light">{{product.price| number : '1.2-2'}}€ </ion-label>   
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options side="end" (ionSwipe)="itemSwipe($event)">
         <ion-item-option expandable color="danger">Löschen</ion-item-option>
      </ion-item-options>
   </ion-item-sliding>
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmgrq.png)

And here is the TS methode:

```
onDrag(event) {
event.target.getSlidingRatio().then(res=> {
  if(res > 0){
    console.log("DELTE");
    this.showArchiveSlide = false;
    this.showDeleteSlide = true;
  }
  if(res == 0){
    console.log("IDLE");
    this.showArchiveSlide = true;
    this.showDeleteSlide = true;
  }
  if(res < 0){
    console.log("SAVE");
    this.showArchiveSlide = true;
    this.showDeleteSlide = false;
  }
  this.slideWidth = res;
  console.log(res);
});
```

}

[TS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAVQz.png)

This is the output:
[Console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbK4i.png)

As soon as i release the item-sliding the (ionDrag) stops emitting the position.

I am thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Oldie, but no one is helping...

small tip: you don't need the promise there in the event, there is a detail param that contains your ratio... event.detail: {amount: 1, ratio: 0.45}

to answer the real question: I am looking for the same, and it seems it is not possible without hacking around. I am working in Ionic5, but this works for at least Ionic 4 too.

```
@ViewChild('yourList') yourList: IonItemSliding;
...
ngAfterViewinit(){
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
            if(mutation.target.classList.contains('item-sliding-active-slide')){
                // do when active
                return;
            }
            //do when close
        });
    });

    observer.observe(this.yourList.el,{attributes: true});
}
```

this just listens to the classList of your ion-item-sliding element. When the class is available, the slide is open (or at least partly) and when the class is not available, the slide is closed.

you can also listen for "item-sliding-active-options-end" and "item-sliding-active-options-start" in case you need to know which one is open.

There seems to be a small delay on the closed part however. To detect if it's actually closed you could add a MutationObserver that observes the style.transform on each ion-item. If this is empty, the slider is closed.

Also: do not be alarmed when your ide warns you about classList,style.transform or this.yourList.el. all are available. The former two says the given definition does not define such property, and the latter just says that the typescript has a private modifier. Since it is being transpiled to vanilla javascript anyway, it works, because javascript does not have private modifiers, and the targets are just HTMLElements.